# Construct function from data points

Tags: functions, continuity

I am trying to construct a function from a couple of data points meeting certain criteria, but the process is very confusing to me and the other posts here are all answered with methods to obtain a polynomial function, which, I believe, would be ill-suited for my purposes. Could you construct a function meeting the criteria and/or show me a time-efficient method?

Here's the criteria for a function f(x):

1. $f(x):[0;+\infty)\to[0;1)^1$;
2. $f(x)$ is continuous and monotonic: $f(0) = 0 \ \ \&\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x) = 1$;
3. For any $z \ge 0 \ \ f'(z)\gt 0\ \&\ f''(z) \lt 0$;
4. An exact correspondence between the inputs and values in the table given below is ideal, and an error $\delta \leq 10^6$ is required;

And here's the data points:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & 5 & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
\hline
 f(x) & .2 & .4 & .6 & .8 & .9 & .95 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Thank you in advance!
note$^1$ : This function has to do with a passion project and is going to be implemented in a C# algorithm, so only positive values are ever going to be fed to it. What happens at $x \notin [0;3.4\cdot10^{38}]$ doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I think you can use a fairly normal approach for finding a polynomial but use some different functions ($e^{-x}, 1/x$, etc) instead, I'll give it a shot then get back to you

Comment: Do you just want an approximate fit or a function that exactly runs through these point? If its just an approximation, a shifted/scaled sigmoid fit would probably do a good job. Also, do the values correspond to some kind of cumulative distribution function?

Comment: @Tyberius I do need an exact function, though  it is going to run on a C# algorithm so a precision of 6+ decimal places works too, and no, they do not.

Comment: @TheMarty27. Are you dreaming ?

Answer (score 0):

Classic curve fitting:

[image]

$$f(x) = \frac{ArcSinh (.182132\ x)}{\pi}$$

Comment: Thank you for your time, but there are a couple of issues with this answer: 1. The values are unexact (I am going to add this to the criteria list) and 2. At around $x \ge 53.4 \ f(x) \ge 1$, though $f(x)$ needs to converge to 1 as $x \to \infty$.